# Custom UITabbarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want input a button into `UITabbarController` for handle event as tab bar of instagram app.

Image in this link:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8

I hope everybody help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this. Has wht you are looking for. Read around the other posts on the site as well. It helped me a lot.

http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/